# Load a model with not autoincremental id

Tags: model

I have created a model that uses unique string as ID field, no issue for saving it after setting  `protected  $_isPkAutoIncrement = false;` in `Mysql4` resource however I'm facing an issue when I try to load it:

`->load('mystrinid')` return me this error:

```
Invalid method MY_MODULE_Model_Mymodel::load(Array
(
    [0] => mystrinid
)
```

**UPDATE**:

this is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` (the model) and `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract` / `Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract` (resource model) define `load()`, so there's something amiss with your class inheritance.

Comment: Agreed. 
@Francesco, can you post your class definition? Also you module is named : MY_MODULE ? with clas myModel? You should name the properly ;)

Comment: you are right it is working fine